# How to add block in jinja2 template via python script

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to add other rendered templates to the main template in which I have already inserted values. The best way I see to do this is to **add blocks** and then insert into those blocks when rendering. (If anyone knows a better way, would appreciate an idea)

For example, we have `main.j2`:

```
adress: {{ address }}
port: {{ port }}
services:
```

services that have their own fields:

```
type: {{ type }}
timeout: {{ timeout }}
retry: {{ retry }}
```

As a result, I want to get the file `main.j2`:

```
address: {{ adress }}
port: {{ port }}
services:
  name: Service1
  type: DNS
  timeout: 30s
  retry: true
  
  name: Service2
  type: DNS
  timeout: 30s
  retry: true
  num_retry: 4
  retry_timeout: 5s
```

As I said, my services have **different fields** that I have to fill in, so I render them separately, but then I need to create **a single file** from them.

So far, I've only found how to skip some blocks when rendering the template.

Comment: "I need to add other rendered templates to the main template in which I have already inserted values," by this do you mean you have templated a file, and you wish to append additional text to the file after it is templated? Can you post the Python you are using to template the file(s)? My initial thought was to just use a Jinja2 loop to loop through a variable `services` but I'm unsure of the context behind your problem.

Comment: No I have a main file in which I want to insert the templated ones. Going through for is a really handy idea - it's the easiest way to implement it. (And do everything in one jinja2 file) But I have multiple blocks of data in services (for example I only need to pass 5 values to 1 service, another more than 20) and passing a huge set of data to 1 template is not very convenient. Now I'm trying to get rid of it by rendering each service separately and then inserting them into the final file. This way it's even more convenient and easier to parse the config file, from where I take the data.

Comment: I did a quick run through the jinja documentation so far and looked in the public domain, but couldn't find how I could insert blocks like - {% blockname service1 %}{% endblock %} - This is what I need

Comment: Refer to my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I have not found in the documentation how you can specify it.

```
{% block service1 %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the method template.render() returns a string, so, it is possible to give a whole service file, with constants and additional variables, and then this service will be a string, which can be easily added to the list and used in the jinja template using for
[image]

```
{% for service in list %}
  {{ service }}
{% endfor %}
```

Add data from the rendered template to the main file. There are also problems with indentation, but this can easily be solved with

```
{{ service|indent(num) }} # -> insert instead of num the number of spaces that are needed
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I think I understand, however I would argue using a Jinja2 for loop *is* the most convenient way to go about this problem. Specifically, use a nested loop.

Assuming your `services` variable looks something like this (can be formatted in a number of different ways, but this made sense to me):

```
(YAML)
services:
  - name: service1
    property_1: 1
    property_2: 2
  - name: service2
    property_1: 1
    property_2: 2
    property_3: 3

(Python Dictionary)
services = {
    [
        {
            'name': 'service1',
            'property_1': 1,
            'property_2': 2
        },
        {
            'name': 'service2',
            'property_1': 1,
            'property_2': 2,
            'property_3': 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Jinja2 template:

```
services:
{% for service in services %}
   - name: {{ service['name'] }} # your output looks like it needs to be YAML, so we use the name property of the service as the first element in the object.
{% for property, value in service.items() %}
   {% if property != 'name' %} # make sure not to duplicate the 'name' property
     {{ property }}: {{ value }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
services:
   - name: service1
     property_1: 1
     property_2: 2
   - name: service2
     property_1: 1
     property_2: 2
     property_3: 3
```

This will work regardless of the number of properties each service has.

Comment: Yes, that's the decision I want to get rid of. Again for the reason that in addition to the different number of variables and different blocks, I also have constants that are enclosed in these data blocks. 
(By block I mean a yaml block, like a separate indent). Here already the search of data from the dictionary will not help. You need to put conditions on all the blocks, if the data you want to insert into these blocks. If yes, we generate them, if no we skip them.

Comment: So my jinja file turns into an unsupported environment and difficult to edit (at some point), in which only I will be able to break, while other colleagues will have to spend time to understand what I have done. So I would specifically like to know if it is possible to somehow insert {% blockname %} into the file via a script through the jinja2 library.

Comment: Have you investigated [template inheritance](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#template-inheritance)? You can use multiple template files to extend a base template.

Comment: Thanks for the help **Crock**, but using extensions didn't help me either. That's why I did it differently.